# How can I retrieve records with an optional join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I am looking to retrieve a set of Time records for a user.  The query should return records scoped to a network that are either public (i.e., private == false) or private (i.e., private == true) and the user has a Slot record for that Time.

I'd like to do this with ActiveRecord, but the only way I've found how is to do two separate queries.  That is fine with the exception of the result being an array instead of an ActiveRecord relation preventing chainging, etc.

Any suggestions?

```
class TimeAccessPolicy
  attr_reader :network

  def initialize(network)
    @network = network
  end

  def accessible_times_for(user)
    return [] unless user.is_member_of?(network)
    times = network.times.where(private: false)
    times + network.times.joins(:slots).where(private: true, slots: {user_id: user.id})
  end
end
```

-- Edit:

```
class Time < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
  has_many   :slots
  has_many   :participants, through: :slots, source: :user

  # has private boolean
  ...
end

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :memberships, as: :memberable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :users, through: :memberships
  has_many   :times

  ...
end

class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :time

  ...
end
```

Comment: Could you post a little more context,  I think you want to add some scopes to your models. Post the Network model , explain where times comes from,  is it a has_many relationship in Network Model?  Whenever I hear 'preserve ActiveRecord relation', I immediately think of scopes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scoped method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes)

Like this:

```
times = network.times.scoped
# times is still ActiveRecord relation
if private
  times = times.joins(:slots).where(private: true, slots: {user_id: user.id})
else
  times = times.where(private: false)
end
```

This code does only one query